# Is there any +ve integer solution for $2^x - 2^y=3(n-1)$

Tags: analysis

$2^x-2^y = 3(n-1)$

where $3(n-1) > 0$

$x, y$ & $n$ are positive integers

Comment: Please use mathjax for formatting and show your attempts.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: $x=3$, $y=1$, $n=3$

Comment: There are infinitely many. Take any $x,y$ with the same parity (ie both odd or both even).and $x>y$.

Comment: There are infinite combinations. All you want is $2^x-2^y$ to be a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 0):

2^{x}  = 2^{2p + k}. (Where x = 2p + k and k can take values 0 or 1)

Clearly above thing is equal to 4 ^{p} * 2^{k}

(3+1)^{p}*2^{k}

Clearly if we divide the number by 3 the remainder only depends on k.(as first term always give remainder which can be proved by binomial expansion)

If k is 0 then remainder is 1 and if k is 1 then remainder is 2.

For 2 numbers 'a' and 'b' such that a-b is a multiple of 3 they both should give equal remainders when divided by 3.

Therefore the 'x' and 'y' should be simultaneously odd or even and x should be greater than y. Naturally there will be an infinite number of solutions.